# Angular Universal 13 Not Working with Service Worker on View Source

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-universal, angular-service-worker

Here are exact instructions:

1. `npm i -g @angular/cli` - installs latest version 13
2. `ng new test` - then open project
3. `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine`
4. `ng add @angular/pwa`

This is pretty standard stuff...

5. `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr`

Open your browser to `http://localhost:4000/` and view source.

You will only see the browser version, not the server ssr version.

In the case you have some cached pages, open a new private browser window. I still only see the regular Angular Version NOT the Angular Universal Version.  I can change the port to something I have NEVER used before, and I still get the browser version (the HTML is not generated from the server).

However, if I run the dev server with `npm run dev:ssr`, everything works as expected.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Thanks,

J

Comment: Yes, I think this is done on purpose. If you were to use `ctrl` + refresh when viewing the source code, you will see the SSR'ed response. This is what search engines will fetch when crawling your site, since they don't use the service worker. I don't think you should be bothered by it...

Comment: Thanks, I turned off cookies and it worked!